# Ansible loop over variables

Tags: ansible

i am using ansible to update configuration file of newly added NIC
for that i have  defined some variables in separate yml file

**/tmp/ip.yml**

```
#first interface
interface1: eth1
bootproto1: static
ipaddress1: 192.168.211.249
netmask1: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.211.2
DNS1: 192.168.211.2

#second interface
interface2: eth2
bootproto2: static
ipaddress2: 10.0.0.100
netmask2: 255.0.0.0
```

**Playbook**

```
- include_vars: /tmp/ip.yml

- name: configuring interface 
  lineinfile:
    state=present
    create=yes
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{interface1}}
    regexp="{{ item.regexp }}"
    line="{{ item.line }}"
  with_items:
     - { regexp: '^BOOTPROTO=.*', line: 'BOOTPROTO={{interface1}}' }
     - { regexp: '^IPADDR=.*', line: 'IPADDR={{ipaddress1}' }
     - { regexp: '^NETMASK=.*', line: 'NETMASK={{netmask1}}' }
     - { regexp: '^GATEWAY=.*', line: 'GATEWAY={{gateway}}' }
     - { regexp: '^PEERDNS=.*', line: 'PEERDNS=no' }
     - { regexp: '^DNS1=.*', line: 'DNS1={{DNS1}}' }
     - { regexp: '^ONBOOT=.*', line: 'ONBOOT={{onboot}}' }
when: bootproto1 == 'static'

- name: configuring for DHCP
  lineinfile:
   state=present
   create=yes
   dest=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{interface1}}
   regexp="{{ item.regexp }}"
   line="{{ item.line }}"
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '^BOOTPROTO=.*',line: 'BOOTPROTO={{bootproto1}}' }
    - {regexp: '^PEERDNS=.*',line: 'PEERDNS=yes' }
    - { regexp: '^ONBOOT=.*', line: 'ONBOOT={{onboot}}' }
when: bootproto1 == 'dhcp'
```

similarly repeated for second interface.

Even Though this method works for 2 NIC,this is too difficult to manage ,that is for each new NIC added i need to modify playbook and update corresponding variable in **/tmp/ip.yml**.

Is there a way to add variables to /tmp/ip.yml and may be using some separator parse it to playbook with out modifying playbook each time for plugging in new NIC.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a lot to say here.
First, try to avoid `lineinfile` like plague. It is really a *last-resort* solution. `lineinfile` makes it hard to write consistent and idempotents playbooks.

Now, since you're trying to populate RH style interface files, it is quite easy to do.

**Organize your variables**

The first thing to do is to have a proper structure for your variables. You'll want to loop over your interfaces so you have to make stuff 'loopable'. Having `interface1`, `interface2` ... `interfaceN` is not scalable as you mentioned.

Here is a suggestion :

```
interfaces_ipv4:
  - name: eth0
    bootproto: static
    ipaddress: 192.168.211.249
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    gateway: 192.168.211.2
    dns: 192.168.211.2
  - name: eth2
    bootproto: static
    ipaddress: 10.0.0.100
    netmask: 255.0.0.0
```

**Write your template**

Now that you have your data, you need a template to create your OS config file.

```
BOOTPROTO={{item.bootproto}}
IPADDR={{item.ipaddress}}
NETMASK={{item.netmask}}
{% if item.gateway is defined %}
GATEWAY={{item.gateway}}
{% endif %}
PEERDNS=no
DNS1={{item.dns}}
ONBOOT={{item.onboot|default('no')}}
```

I included two variations : you can skip outputting a line when it's not set (`{% if ... %}` construct) or provide default values (for instance `{{item.onboot|default('no')}}`).

Your mileage may vay, depending if you want to use a default or to skip with the if construct.

**Create a task**

Finally, here is a task that will create interface configuration files for each interface :

```
- name: Push template
  template: 
    src=/path/to/the/above/template.j2
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{item.name}}.cfg
  with_items:
    - "{{ interfaces_ipv4 }}"
```

This should do it all.

Of course, best way to use this task is to add it to some "network" role, and call it from a playbook.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks @leucos if i make changes to var file like you mentioned  http://pastebin.com/ev8gSnH6 then can i still use existing method.
because that variable file is going to contain many more features.

Comment: In your pastebin you are overwriting your variables : you define `interface` as `eth1`, and then redefine it as `eth2` . This is why variables have to be in a list. See `interfaces_ipv4` above (note: this part has been edited, since it was erroneous).